# vectorizing a function of an array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to vectorizing code, and I am really psyched about how much faster everything is, but I can't get the high speed out of this particular piece of code...

Here is the housing class...

```
class GaussianMixtureModel:
    def __init__(self, image_matrix, num_components, means=None):

        self.image_matrix = image_matrix
        self.num_components = num_components
        if(means is None):
            self.means = np.zeros(num_components)
        else:
            self.means = np.array(means)
        self.variances = np.zeros(num_components)
        self.mixing_coefficients = np.zeros(num_components)
```

And here is what I've got so far that works:

```
def likelihood(self):
    def g2(x):

#N =~ 5
#self.mixing_coefficients = 1D, N items
#self.variances = 1D, N items
#self.means = 1D, N items

        mc = self.mixing_coefficients[:,None,None]
        std = self.variances[:,None,None] ** 0.5
        var = self.variances[:,None,None]
        mean = self.means[:,None,None]
        return np.log((mc*(1.0/(std*np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-((x-mean)**2.0)/(2.0*var)))).sum())

    f = np.vectorize(g2)

#self.image_matrix =~ 400*700 2D matrix

    log_likelihood = (f(self.image_matrix)).sum()
    return log_likelihood
```

And here is what I've got that gives a strange result (note that `self.image_matrix` is an nxn matrix of a grayscale image):

```
def likelihood(self):
    def g2():

#N =~ 5
#self.mixing_coefficients = 1D, N items
#self.variances = 1D, N items
#self.means = 1D, N items
#self.image_matrix = 1D, 400x700 2D matrix

        mc = self.mixing_coefficients[:,None,None]
        std = self.variances[:,None,None] ** 0.5
        var = self.variances[:,None,None]
        mean = self.means[:,None,None]
        return np.log((mc*(1.0/(std*np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-((self.image_matrix-mean)**2.0)/(2.0*var)))).sum())

    log_likelihood = (g2()).sum()
    return log_likelihood
```

However, the second version is **really** fast compared to the first (which takes almost 10 seconds...and speed is really important here, because this is part of a convergence algorithm)

Is there a way to replicate the results of the first version and the speed of the second? (And I'm really not familiar enough with vectorizing to know why the second version isn't working)

Comment: What are the dimensions of the other arrays involved? `self.mixing_coefficients`, `self.variances`, and `self.means`? (And where is `self` coming from?)

Comment: I'll edit the answer to include the dims, but the overall class is huge...i'll try to get the important stuff

Comment: In your second version you only seem to be using the top left element in your image matrix (`self.image_matrix[0,0]`)

Comment: no, that was an error in copying over... I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version is so fast because it only uses the first cell of `self.image_matrix`:

```
return np.log((mc*(1.0/(std*np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-((self.image_matrix[0,0]-mean)**2.0)/(2.0*var)))).sum())
#                                                                            ^^^^^
```

This is also why it's completely wrong. It's not actually a vectorized computation over `self.image_matrix` at all. Don't try to use its runtime as a point of comparison; you can always make wrong code faster than right code.

---

By eliminating the use of `np.vectorize`, you can make the first version much faster, but not as fast as the wrong code. The `sum` inside the `log` simply needs the appropriate axis specified:

```
def likelihood(self):
    def f(x):
        mc = self.mixing_coefficients[:,None,None]
        std = self.variances[:,None,None] ** 0.5
        var = self.variances[:,None,None]
        mean = self.means[:,None,None]
        return np.log((mc*(1.0/(std*np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi)))*(np.exp(-((x-mean)**2.0)/(2.0*var)))).sum(axis=0))

    log_likelihood = (f(self.image_matrix)).sum()
```

This can be further simplified and optimized in a few ways. For example, the nested function can be eliminated, and multiplying by `1.0/whatever` is slower than dividing by `whatever`, but eliminating `np.vectorize` is the big thing.

Comment: no, that was an error in copying over...I corrected it...but I think the axis will work-thank you!

Comment: and...that is good to know about vectorize...the speed increase from changing the axis is exactly what I was expecting.  Thanks again